# WPF calculate Parent margin based on child control position

Tags: wpf, rulers

I have following XAML. I have to set margin to `CanvasRuler` as per child control (`LabelEditFrame`) Left position. How do I do that.

```xml
   <wpfcommon:CanvasNavigationBar>
        <DockPanel>
            <wpfcommon:CanvasRuler />     <!-- Horizontal -->
            </wpfcommon:CanvasRuler  />   <!-- Vertical -->
            <border>
                <StackPanel>
                    <wpfcommon:LabelEditFrame>
                    </ wpfcommon:LabelEditFrame>
                </StackPanel>
            </border>
        </DockPanel>
    </wpfcommon:CanvasNavigationBar>
```

Right now I have this

[image]

I want to have this (*I can do that by setting hard coded value, but I need to set it dynamically, so if position of child control gets changes, it will change ruler position automatically*).

[image]

Comment: What would cause the user control to move like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, if this is on a Canvas and are children on a canvas, you can use the

```
Canvas.SetLeft
```

and

```
Canvas.SetTop
```

methods.

So for the Rulers, you can set the:

```
VerticalAlignment="Top", HorizontalAlignment="Left
```

Then when the LabelEditFrame is moved (whichever event you use to trigger that), you can adjust the two rulers with something like this:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(HorizontalCanvasRuler, LabelEditFrame.Margin.Left);
Canvas.SetTop(VerticalCanvasRuler, LabelEditFrame.Margin.Top);
```

I haven't tried this out, but I have used to adjust controls like this before so it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put all that stuff to Grid and allow it calculate anything for you:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="SomeFixedHeightToGetTopMargin"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition  Width="SomeFixedWithToGetLeftMargin"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <wpfcommon:CanvasRuler Grid.Column="1"/>
    <wpfcommon:CanvasRuler Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <StackPanel>
            <wpfcommon:LabelEditFrame/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```